# filtering bootstrap with mvc

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I have Sectors and Projects for each Sector show in  Gallery with filtering bootstrap

```
                   <div align="center">

                    <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="hdpe">الزجاج </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="sprinkle">الصيانة</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="spray">الاستثمار العقاري</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="irrigation">المقاولات</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="all">الكل</button>
                </div>

                <div class="gallery_product col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter sprinkle">
                    <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/365x365/" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="gallery_product col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter hdpe">
                    <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/365x365/" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="gallery_product col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter irrigation">
                    <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/365x365/" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="gallery_product col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter spray">
                    <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/365x365/" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
```

what should I ues @foreach ? and how will connect and reapet correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

As per your question I understand that you want to use foreach loop to display multiple images in view using .net MVC. Answer is yes you can use foreach loop to write less code. You have to retrieve URL of images from model.Consider below model file.

**GalleryModel.cs**

```
public class GalleryModel
{
    public string ImagePath{get;set;}

    public List<Gallery> AllImages()
    {
      //insert AllImages from database or store it into list as static as per your requirement
      //return List<Gallery>
    }
}
```

Create controller and write action method:

```
public class GaleeryController  :Controller
{
    //import statements
    //import your model class too

    public ActionResult Gallery()
    {   
      GalleryModel gallery=new GalleryModel();
      return View(gallery.AllImages());
    }
}
```

create view of above method.

**Gallery.cshtml**

```
//use gallery model class here
@model IEnumerable<YourProject.Models.GalleryModel>
```

```
                <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="hdpe">الزجاج </button>
                <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="sprinkle">الصيانة</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="spray">الاستثمار العقاري</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="irrigation">المقاولات</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="all">الكل</button>
```

```
@foreach(var item in model)
{
     <div class="gallery_product col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter sprinkle">
           <img src="@item.ImagePath" class="img-responsive">
     </div>
}
```